# Ajax json value in multiple div with same id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a ajax request that getting json value from php page like

```
{"Inboxunreadmessage":4}
```

And here is my ajax JS

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: "/mail/mail-action",
        data: {
            _act: "load"
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        if(data.message){
            showMessage(data);
        }
        $('#Inboxunreadmessage').html(data.Inboxunreadmessage);
    }).error(function(jqxhr, exception){
        ajaxErrorHandler(jqxhr, exception);
    });
});
```

Its working properly but when i use div id like

```
<span id="Inboxunreadmessage"></span>
<span id="Inboxunreadmessage"></span>
<span id="Inboxunreadmessage"></span>
```

Its showing value only in one div (in First Div)

Comment: Would you be surprised if there were 3 other Deepak Saini with the same ids (passports) and on pay day only the first one would get the salary? Don't duplicated ids, they are unique identifiers in document. Use class instead: `class="Inboxunreadmessage"`, `$('.Inboxunreadmessage').html(data.Inboxunreadmessage)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Having 2 elements with the same ID is not valid html according to the W3C specification.**

So id only work once at first position on page

if you want append value in all div then change id to class

```
<span class="Inboxunreadmessage"></span>
<span class="Inboxunreadmessage"></span>
<span class="Inboxunreadmessage"></span>


$(window).load(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: "/mail/mail-action",
        data: {
            _act: "load"
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        if(data.message){
            showMessage(data);
        }
        $('.Inboxunreadmessage').html(data.Inboxunreadmessage);
    }).error(function(jqxhr, exception){
        ajaxErrorHandler(jqxhr, exception);
    });
});
```